# Use object from directive inside child directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have two directives. The outer directives needs to get some information from a service and then use that object for the inner directive. But I can't figure out how to do this correctly. Here's some sample code, in which I imagine I have some colored pencils, and we need to retrieve the pencil information based on the ID to figure out the pencil's color:

```
<div pencil-directive pencil-id="7"></div>
```

---

```
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('sampleController', function($scope){
  $scope.color = "red";
})

.directive('colorDirective', function(){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: "<span ng-class='color'>{{color}}</span>",
    scope: {
      color: '='
    }
  }
})

.directive('pencilDirective', ["$timeout", function($timeout){
  return{
    restrict: "A",
    template: "<div>Pencil {{pencilId}} is " +
      "<color-directive color='pencil-color'> </div>",
    scope: {
      pencilId: "@",
      pencilColor: "=?"
    },
    controller: function($scope){
      //simulate getting the pencil color from a service
      $timeout(function(){
        $scope.pencilColor = "blue";
      }, 10)

    }
  }
}])
```

I would expect that to look like this:

```
Pencil 7 color is blue.
```

But instead it ends up just looking like this:

```
Pencil 7 color is 0
```

I assume that's because `pencilColor` isn't initalized by the time the `colorDirective` sees it and it isn't updated later, but I don't know the "angular way" of making this work.

[Here's a plunk.](http://plnkr.co/edit/m7vtUv80kYcbAqIZgIre?p=preview) Note that I'm on Angular 1.2 since we're still supporting IE 8 (for now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is the way your binding between your parent directive and child.

Your using `scope.pencilColour` but passing it into your child directive with `pencil-color`.

When using scope properties and attributes for your directives then the dash is needed. However when using them to bind with in your template. Either with `{{}}` or passing them into a sub-directives attributes your do not need the dash and can use the scope property as defined.

So change `<color-directive color='pencil-color'> </div>` to `<color-directive color='pencilColor'> </div>`

See plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/mVCKLWgknwg81SUkIRtf?p=preview

---

EDIT:
Not too sure if ive explained that very well maybe this will help.

```
<!--Here we need the dash as were referencing it as a html attribute-->

<div pencil-directive pencil-color="'green'"></div>

<!--However in the directives template when we bind we use it as defined on our scope-->

{{pencilColor}}

<!--Even when passing it into a sub directive. The sub directives attribute needs the dash but our current one doesn't.-->

<sub-directive sub-prop="pencilColor" />
```

---

Comment: Sigh... so much simpler than I was making it out to be. :D